# How to change color of text based on the php condition

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have 2 input fields and a input submit button, simple stupid, the php code works, basically just an if statement generating a direct link, how can I get the variable that the link gets stored in to be a different color in the input box if the variable is === to an error?

for example i want it to be red if the link is not valid.

would i just jquery or php? or just some simple html or css that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use AJAX to dynamically change color through Jquery.